# Runtime error : NullPointerException in android although it is working on java normally

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.climaconproject; 

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.Collection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.nxp.jip.JIPImpl;
import com.nxp.jip.PacketHandlerIPv6;
import com.nxp.jip.exception.JipException;
import com.nxp.jip.service.JenNetIPNetwork;
import com.nxp.jip.service.Node;
import com.nxp.jip.service.Service;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView display= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    PacketHandlerIPv6 my_packet = new PacketHandlerIPv6();
    JIPImpl my_jip = new JIPImpl(my_packet);
    Service service =new Service(my_jip);   
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

}
```

and the runtime error is

```
Fatal exception: receive
java.lang.NullExceptionPointer 
at com.nxp.jip.PacketHandlerIPv6$ReceiveWorker.run(PAcketHandlerIPv6.java:223)
```

When i run the same lines of the code on a java program it works normally but in android the NullPointerException runtime error appears

Comment: Do you have INTERNET permission in manifest?

Comment: Can you show us what happens in the com.nxp.jip.PacketHandlerIPv6.java file at line  223 ? ALso maybe you should post the whole stack trace and not just the first line.

Comment: @laalto No i did not make any permission and i don't know how

Comment: @XGouchet it is an imported library i don't know what is inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need at least the internet permission. Edit your AndroidManifest.xml and add

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

inside the `manifest` element i.e. outside `application`.